# Instant app only working on 8.0 devices

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have deployed my app to play store. It is released on production. It works fine on google's pixel only. When I tap the link on Samsung devices I see instant app loading screen for few seconds (see the screenshot below) and the URL is handled by the browser (chrome in my case) instead of loading the instant app. However, buzz feed's instant app (https://www.buzzfeed.com/tasty) works absolutely fine.

Here (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O1ZQkEcOUiTIkHZN3_QA94gTZCY-ppYo/view?usp=sharing) is the link to my log file when I tap the link. I don't see anything on Logcat.

[image]

Comment: can you share complete device details to identify issues.

Comment: @sam33r, This can be a device specific issue. I would suggest you to submit your project to Google's [Issue-tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues). They will take a look at it. (also, please share the link to that filed bug here)

Comment: @sam33r I hope it has been resolve.

Comment: Yea it works now.

Comment: can you post your answer here. Thanks.